# How to do multiple wildcard search in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Example :
I've table with Name,Contact,City

Then from UI I get Multiple Cities list

```
Select * from Person where City = 'Frankfort','Texas','Washington'
```

I need the Condition like above.

Note: I've total search Parameters 57
For all 57 Columns I need multiple search.

This is how I written the condition
Do we have any better Approach to Do It.

```
((@CityIS NULL) OR (';' + @City+ ';' like '%;' + City+ ';%'))
```

Comment: Are you looking for [`IN`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/in-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16)?  `SELECT * FROM Person WHERE City IN ('Frankfort','Texas','Washington')`

Comment: *"Do we have any better Approach to Do It"* Use a table type parameter?

Comment: concatinate all 57 columns and search for %Frankfurt% and an or for all further cities, but 57 columns seems a bit much to search for cities, maybe a redesign is in order

Answer (score 0):

If you want to search 57 values in one column (city)  .This code is correct

You can use table-valued parameter   to solve the problem

you must create a table-valued parameter and Create PROCEDURE

```
CREATE TYPE SourceKeyList AS TABLE ( 
  SourceKey NVARCHAR(50)
)
GO



go

CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.stp_GetPerson
@source_key_list SourceKeyList READONLY
AS
BEGIN

 
 
 SELECT c.*
 FROM dbo.Person c
 JOIN @source_key_list k ON k.SourceKey = c.City
END
GO


DECLARE @source_key_list SourceKeyList

INSERT INTO @source_key_list
SELECT 'Frankfort' UNION ALL
SELECT 'Texas' UNION ALL
SELECT 'Washington'

EXEC dbo.stp_GetPerson @source_key_list
GO
```

You can create insert Base data  with the following statements:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Person (
 Id  INT IDENTITY NOT NULL,
 Name NVARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
 City  NVARCHAR(50) NOT NULL 
)
insert into dbo.Person
(Name,City)
select 'A','Frankfort'
union  select 'b','Texas'
union  select 'c','San'
union  select 'c','Washington'
```